# Google Wallet OpenID

Tags: android-pay

I'm working on an HTML5 App for the Chrome Store and intend to use google wallet for micro transactions. Implementation looks straight forward except I'm not sure how to identify the user on the post message after a successful transaction. I'm assuming I will need to use the open ID flow to obtain the user information so I can record the transaction in my database but was hoping I'm missing something and there's a simple way for the wallet SDK to also post the user Google OpenID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the application needs to request the openid itself since there appears to be no session information returned about the current openid